# What is the equivalent of document.querySelectorAll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have cards and when I click to two of them I want to collect the value of data-index for each one

I did it but in vanilla js way
and I'm wondering if it's a correct way to do this in react? and if there another way?

```
  const match = () => {
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".clicked").length === 2) {
      let card1 = document.querySelectorAll(".clicked")[0];
      let card2 = document.querySelectorAll(".clicked")[1];

      if (card1.dataset.index === card2.dataset.index) {
        console.log("yay!");
      } else {
        setInterval(() => {
          card1.classList.remove("clicked");
          card2.classList.remove("clicked");
        }, 1500);
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hmm, there is almost certainly a more react-y way to do this, but it is very hard to advise without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (The scaffolding for your cards would be useful, so people can fiddle). Broadly, you'd do this with React state, rather than by querying the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is please read this [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-document-queryselector#:%7E:text=The%20equivalent%20of%20the%20document,on%20the%20ref%20%2C%20e.g.%20ref.)
Have a great day

Comment: The linked article is fine, but there is no reason to be using refs for this particular problem. Will likely overcomplicate things.

Comment: Oh I see if you want improve your code
Let cards=document.querySelectorAll(".clicked");
By this instead of creating variables iterate cards array to make your code simple

Comment: this is the equivalent of document.querySelector not document.querySelectorAll.. in my example I want to get the length of classes named "clicked" how can I get that in ref?